# Can I customize Content MathML for place value of a number?

Tags: xml, xslt, customization, mathml

I am working on representing maths to the blinds.

I read about how to customize Content MathML from this article "Customizing and Extending Content MathML" http://www.math.uah.edu/siegrist/MathML/index.html It is really helpful. But still I have some questions:

1. I want to describe every single place value of a number (e.g. with color or other attributes), how can I do that? For example:

   `<apply><plus/>
     <ci>256</ci>
     <ci>12</ci>
    </apply>`

to

```
`<apply><plus/>
  <ci><valueH color="red">2</valueH><valueT>5</valueT><valueU>6</valueU></ci>
  <ci><valueT>1</valueT><valueU>2</valueU></ci>
</apply>`
```

2. Can I assign attributes to an element in Content MathML, or just Presentation MathML?

If you have any suggestion, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: How are you rendering the MathML?

Comment: I would render it with a customized XSLT under Java and/or XHTML development. I hope this is possible. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like it will depend entirely on what your xslt will produce. Or are you looking for suggestions for rendering workflows?

Comment: I just wonder if my customized elements (e.g. <ci><valueH color="red">2</valueH><valueT>5</valueT><valueU>6</valueU></ci>) will work using just XSLT, or there are other clever solutions to identify the single place values of a number?